# I want to know what can i do with google maps embedded into a website

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

So im working on a project (I will put a link at the end of the post so you can see )
I want to know can i modify google maps and give accounts , let my users put their buissnies on the map and also informations about that buissnies(list of articles in the store ) .When im done with that i want that my users without account can see their buissnies when they search for some article (but only when they are close that store ) . If you dont understund i will give you this link . You will get it :) 
http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/9946/screenshot1ky.png

Comment: And what's exactly your programming question?

Comment: Well , i wrote it all up there . Cant you see on your own :S

Answer (score 3):

you can place the map on your website and use google-maps-api (javascript or flash...) to interact with the map (navigate the map to a specified location or add different kinds of objects to the map...). You can use database to store information of your users' businesses, display those information on the map (or display the map on the articles...). Other features like searching nearby shops... can be easily implemented.

...but there are plenty of working system out there with similar features...
(the project I'm working on has those features too, and a lot more)
so good luck

Comment: Thanks for reply, that really helps :) Can you just point me somewhere to learn more about informations you gave me and put it on my web page :)

Comment: you can take a look at [the google maps api page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) first